# jquery mobile listview doesn't update correctly-- interaction issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to develop a web app using jQuery mobile and I have found a weird problem.

In the code I use the function `getJSON` to extract informations from a php converted file and store it  (not all the informations extracted) into a multidimensional array:

```
var PL=[];
tempJsonindex=0;
tempPlaylistIndex=0;
loaderPlayslistName=1;
var containerList=' ';
$.getJSON("tracce.php", function(json) {


$.each(json.playlists,function(i,playlist){
        $(" #playlistL").append($('<li/>', {
                class: 'playlistQueue',
                'data-icon':'headphones',
                val: i
                }).append($('<a/>', {   
                'data-transition': 'slide',
                'text': playlist.playlistName
        })));


        PL[i]=[];
        $.each(playlist.tracks,function(j,track){
        PL[i].push({"name":track.name,"artist":track.artist,"file":track.file,"cover":track.cover,"stars":track.stars,"mood":track.mood});


        });

    });
});
```

In the "`playlistL`" listview there are entries that indicates playlists; the idea is to add the selectioned playlist's tracksinto a jQuery mobile's listview (queueL) positioned in another page.

This is the snippet of the code: when I click on a particular button (`addToQueueB`), the JS take the array associated to the selectioned playlist and populates the queue with the element inside it in a listview's tagged form, i.e:

```
$("#addToQueueB").click(function(){
    var temp=PL[selectedPL];
    $(" #queueL").trigger("create")

    for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        $(" #queueL").append($('<li/>', {
        class: 'songInQueue ui-state-disabled',
        val: indexQueue,
        "data-icon":"stop",
        id: "e"+indexQueue,
        }).append($('<a/>', {   
        'data-transition': 'slide',
        'text': temp[i].name+ "-"+temp[i].artist
        }).append($('<img/>',{
        'src':temp[i].cover
        })).append($('<h2/>',{
        'text':temp[i].name
        })).append($('<p/>'),{
        'text':temp[i].artist
        })));
        indexQueue++;
    }
});
```

The problem is when I go to the `queueL`'s page, the listview is populated correctly but I'cant interact with it's elements!

Moreover, if I add another group of tracks clicking to another playlist, the new elements are not displayed correctly in the listview.

I tried to insert everywhere `trigger("create")` and/or `.listview("refresh")`, but often it comes an error o the console, that is (for refresh) :

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

What can I do?

Comment: `.listview("refresh")` should be added after appending all elements, e.g. after for loop. You get that error because the widget isn't ready to accept any enhancement method / argument.

Comment: This,associated with "       $.mobile.loadPage('#queueP',{prefetch:"true"})" where "queueP" is the listview's page, remove any error thank you! The problem that remains is that I can't interact with the listview, i.e. if i select an entry of it, a js function activated by the class associated to the element highlights it, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: *queueP* is a page? If yes, use `$.mobile.changePage('#queueP')`  after updating the listview without calling any enhancement method I.e `refresh`. If I understand your problem, this will work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Without any refresh call the list is not visualized correclty, and the interaction problem persist... :-(

Comment: Is `queueP` a page or not? Why are using loadpage? I'm trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Ops I'm sorry for the incomplete answer! Yew queueP is a page. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, you are updating the listview and then moving to the page, right? As I mentioned on my previous comment, use changePage not loadpage after you update the listview.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this trick but nothing. The weird thing is if a look at the page code in firefox console i can se that the listview is correctly populated!

Comment: Did you get any error? Can you post what you did exactly?

Comment: I solved the issue! I have just replaced the calling "click" function for activate the properties for the class ".songInQueue" with the function $(document).on("click",".songInQueue",function(.... and everything works. Thank you again for your help!